# My activity become blank when i toggle Auto-rotate screen setting

Tags: android, screen-orientation, orientation-changes

I have an activity with a list of data i am handling screen orientation with:

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("someExpensiveObject", videoEntityList);

    }
```

and

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in menifest.

When when my activity is open and i toggle auto-rotation in device settings activity becomes blank.

I am not getting the exact reason can some body help me??

Comment: did you implement onConfigurationChanged() ?

Comment: yes i also tried that

Comment: Can you post your class?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have this in your manifest

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Android will not destroy and re-create your activity on rotation. Therefore `onSaveInstanceState` will not even be called.

Either

1. Rmove the orientation setting from configChanges and keep the code to save and restore instance state. If you are using fragments be sure to call `setRetainInstance` on them if you want them to survive orientation changes.
2. **Or** do what is needed in `onConfigurationChanged` (keeping in mind you do not need to save/restore state - it's the same activity).